Conditioning a crawlspace for encapsulation
I have an hvac system in the attic and want to encapsulate my crawlspace.  How do I go about conditioning the air in the crawlspace, as most of what I've read on the subject outlines utilizing hvac system for conditioning?
Materials I have prepped for the project include:
Dehumidifier
Sump pump and Basin
20 mil vapor barrier
2" kingspan greenguard rigid foam board (R10, will likely double up in future to R20)
Closed cell spray foam for gap sealing
Xmas trees and ground staples for attachment.
Area calls for 1-2" termite gap and I'll have to get an electrical permit to run the pump and dehumidifier. Going to use 12/3 thhn in conduit to gfci and tie it into the outside outlet circuit at the junction box.
Can anyone recommend a good seam tape that doesn't cost a fortune or smell like cat pee after a year?

What's your goal? You should probably read some over on Green Building Advisor about this, because it doesn't usually make sense to condition a crawlspace.

It doesn't make sense to me either, but the county seems to require it in the permit process.  Goal is to reduce my winter electric bill($450/mo and it's up a little in summer as well) and make the house cozier with better humidity control.  Link for the virgibia code here: https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/VRC2018P1/part-iii-building-planning-and-construction/VRC2018P1-Ch04-SecR408.3

That code is kind of absurd. I'd love to dive in to it but I honestly think you'll get better answers from a post over at GBA, with link to the code as a 'what would you do?'

Just realized the wording of the code is either/or and not both, so I'm fairly sure the dehumidifier covers it...

Given that read it really looks like you can use 1/1500 of your floor area of cross vent and your vapor barrier to meet the requirement, with no dehumidifier needed.

Already have the dehumidifier and virginia can be pretty moist most of the year anyway, so I'll put it to use...it'll help keep the bugs away if anything...
